# Code gives desired output but keeps on running

Tags: c++, loops, sequence

This code I wrote is supposed to subtract one from the number inputed, or divide by 2 based on whether it is a multiple of 3 or not. However, every time I try to run the code, It outputs the numbers I want but then doesn't stop running. I am new to coding and not sure how to fix this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "Enter a positive number: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 0) {
        cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
    }
    while (n >= 1) {
        if (n % 3 == 0) {
            n = n-1;
            cout << n << endl;
        }
        else if (n % 3 != 0) {
            n = n / 2;
            cout << n << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a screenshot of the output I get. Instead of giving me the opportunity to run the code again it just stays like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't stop running"? Could you show an example of the output you get?

Comment: @cigien I edited it and added a screenshot of my output

Comment: This is better, but please add the output as text, not as an image.

Comment: [List of reasons why you shouldn't use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4581301)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It seems to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/veqTb8).

Comment: I'd guess there's a breakpoint or similar somewhere

Comment: My best suggestion is to step through the program with a debugger and see if you can spot where things went south. If the program is getting stuck in an infinite loop, a good debugger will help you find it within seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you're asking, however, traversing through the code you can identify that nothing is being done to make the code run again. You would need add what you have inside another while loop. This new while loop would be something like while (input != 0) then run everything you have. In your input statement you could say "Please enter a positive number or enter 0 to exit". This is just an example of an approach, but the premise is that you need something to keep this loop running.